# How to get description of a Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item object?

Tags: magento2, quoteitem

**Magento 2.3**

I am having troubles getting the description of a Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item object. I tried using `$item->getDescription()`, but it returns nothing.

Any ideas?

Comment: look in the corresponding class if there's any method named `getDescription()`.

Comment: Can you share the complete code?

Comment: Are you sure, that description is not empty in DB for this specific item ?